# Best way to retrieve data from a Drupal site to an Android App

Tags: android, drupal

What is the right way to retrieve the Drupal site data in an Android app?

Let us say that I need to retrieve 30 nodes of data into a list view, where each row uses layoutInflater. In my situation, I am getting the data from Json code, and then saving them to arrays, then calling each index of data into the a listView row. Is this the right way?

Is it efficient to use 7 arrays to hold the data and continue the process? I feel it is not bulky and inflexible. Am I right?

**Edited :: added JsonCode**

```
receivedJson = Json.getJsonString(Constants.HOST_DOMAIN_NAME
            + serviceEndPoint);

    try {

        /*
         * convert received Json String to Json array with
         * 
         * @getDrupalFinalJsonArray: METHOD
         */
        jsonArray = Json.getDrupalFinalJsonArray(receivedJson,
                objectParent, itemParent);
        /*
         * Define the length of @nodeBodyArray, @nodeAutherNameArray to be
         * the same length of sonArray but -1, since a factecus item added
         * at index(0) this ISSUE SHOULD BE SOLvER !
         */
        nodeTitleArray = new String[jsonArray.length() - 1];
        nodeAuthorNameArray = new String[jsonArray.length() - 1];
        nodeAuthorImageArray = new String[jsonArray.length() - 1];
        nodeCommentCount = new int[jsonArray.length() - 1];
        nodeNid = new int[jsonArray.length() - 1];
        postDate=new String[jsonArray.length()-1];

        nodeNid = Json.convertJsonArrayToIntJavaArray(jsonArray, "nid");
        nodeCommentCount = Json.convertJsonArrayToIntJavaArray(jsonArray,
                "commentcount");
        nodeTitleArray = Json.convertJsonArrayToStringJavaArray(jsonArray,
                "body");
        nodeAuthorNameArray = Json.convertJsonArrayToStringJavaArray(
                jsonArray, "author");
        nodeAuthorImageArray = Json.convertJsonArrayToStringJavaArray(
                jsonArray, "profile");
        postDate=Json.convertJsonArrayToStringJavaArray(jsonArray, Constants.NODE_POST_DATE_TAG);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    adapter = new nodeListAdapter(context,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nodeTitleArray,
            nodeAuthorNameArray, nodeAuthorImageArray, nodeCommentCount,
            nodeNid,postDate); // define the list adapter
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to make Node class with title, nid, author, etc fields. 
And readJson method for reading Node from Json.

For example:

```
Node nodes[] = new Node[jsonArray.length() - 1];
for (int n = 0; n < jsonArray.length() - 2; n++) {
     nodes[n].readJson(jsonArray[n]);
}
```

Where Node.readJson implementation is getting values from json array and set it to appropriate fields.